# Schottky Diode application Master FET Pack connection

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, schematics, bms

TIDA-010208 is a BMS board designed for 10S - 16S battery applications. I am using this board as a reference to create a BMS for a 12S battery setup using BQ796142. While examining the Master FET section of the board (Page 6), I am having difficulty understanding the purpose of the two Schottky Diodes (D45 and D46) connected to the PACK+ pins of the board. The Schottky diodes are connected with reference to the PACK- pin, while the Zener Diodes are connected with a Ground reference (shouldn't the PACK- be grounded as well?). Hence, I am wondering about the purpose and operation of this part. Additionally, I noticed that turning on the CHG FETs requires a simple gate pulse, but for DSG FETs, a more complex network is utilized. Is there any particular reason for this difference?

[image]